# How to get ref in flat list item onpress?

Tags: react-native, screenshot

I am trying to capture screen with react-native-view-shot. On press this.refs.viewShot.capture showing undefined.

Here is my code

Flat list code:

```
<FlatList
                  ref={(list) => this.myFlatList = list}
                  data={this.state.newsListArray}
                  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                  renderItem={this.renderRowItem}
                />
```

render on press link:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {
                Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
                this._captureScreenIos('5c63f7307518134a2aa288ce') :
                this._captureScreenAndroid('5c63f7307518134a2aa288ce')
              }}>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                  <Icon name="share-alt" size={16} color="#ffb6cf" />
                  <Text style={{paddingLeft:6,fontSize:12,fontWeight:'500'}}>Share News</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

And that's the function:

```
_captureScreenIos = (refId) => {
    console.log("Clicked for IOS");
    this.changeLoaderStatus();
    var thisFun = this;
    var viewShotRef = 'viewShot-5c63f7307518134a2aa288ce';
     this.myFlatList.viewShot.capture({width: 2048 / PixelRatio.get(), height: 2048 / PixelRatio.get()}).then(res => {
       RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(res, 'base64').then((base64data) => {
         console.log("base64data",base64data)
         let base64Image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64data}`;
         const shareOptions = {
           title: "My Beauty Squad",
           //message: "Download my beauty squad with below link."+ "\n" + "https://itunes.apple.com/uk/app/my-beauty-squad/id1454212046?mt=8" ,
           url: base64Image,
           subject: "Share news feed"
         };
         Share.open(shareOptions);
         thisFun.changeLoaderStatus();
       })
     }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error, 'this is error');
       this.changeLoaderStatus();
     })
    }
```

Please let me know if anyone having a solution for the same.

**This is my app screen **
[image]

It's blur when we have long list items.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`import { captureRef } from react-native-view-shot`

```
constructor(props) { 
   super(props); 
   this.refs = {}; 
}
```

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
   <TouchableOpacity 
       onPress={ () => { 
           captureRef(this.refs[`${index}`], options).then(.....)   
       }
   > 
      <View 
        style={{flexDirection:'row'}}
        ref={shot => this.refs[`${index}`] = shot}
      >
        ...........
      </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

[React Native View Shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot/blob/master/README.md#capturerefview-options-lower-level-imperative-api)

I hope it help you.

Comment: I am getting this error now "Argument appears to not be a ReactComponent. Keys: 0,1,2,3"

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: It's capturing full of flat list image instead of item screenshot. If anyhow we can remove blur in long images that also solution for me...i am stuck from last 4 days.

Comment: I just added 2 screens 1st one is my screen where each item having share news button on press only that section image will be captured and share...2nd one is if I am adding share button on detail page for some news getting the same issue blur when long data...so it's not working for the both side.

Comment: And not i am very frustrated because of nothing to help me into this.

Comment: <View collapsable={false} ref={(shot) => { this.screenshot = shot; }} >     It's working for me to capture a item but only the issue is left that every time capture last item of list.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: My share link is in the bottom so i can't insert view into this.

Answer (score 1):

That is a good amount of code. Try https://reactnativecode.com/take-screenshot-of-app-programmatically/
setting the state and try passing in the object you are referencing.

```
    export default class App extends Component {

      constructor(){

        super();

        this.state={

          imageURI : 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/motorcycle.jpg'

        }
      }

      captureScreenFunction=()=>{

        captureScreen({
          format: "jpg",
          quality: 0.8
        })
        .then(
          uri => this.setState({ imageURI : uri }),
          error => console.error("Oops, Something Went Wrong", error)
        );

      }
```

Comment: I am using this into flat list, can you share some updated code so that can help me into this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.screenshot = {};
}
```

This is my function:

```
_captureScreenIos(itemId) {
    this.changeLoaderStatus();
    var thisFun = this;
    var viewShotRef = itemId;
     captureRef(this.screenshot[itemId],{format: 'jpg',quality: 0.8}).then(res => {
       RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(res, 'base64').then((base64data) => {
         console.log("base64data",base64data)
         let base64Image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64data}`;
         const shareOptions = {
           title: "My Beauty Squad",
           //message: "Download my beauty squad with below link."+ "\n" + "https://itunes.apple.com/uk/app/my-beauty-squad/id1454212046?mt=8" ,
           url: base64Image,
           subject: "Share news feed"
         };
         Share.open(shareOptions);
         thisFun.changeLoaderStatus();
       })
     }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error, 'this is error');
       this.changeLoaderStatus();
     })
    }
```

This is the view:

```
    <View collapsable={false} ref={(shot) => { this.screenshot[itemId] = shot; }} >
    //some content here

<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {
                Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
                this._captureScreenIos(itemData.item._id) :
                this._captureScreenAndroid(itemData.item._id)
              }}>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                  <Icon name="share-alt" size={16} color="#ffb6cf" />
                  <Text style={{paddingLeft:6,fontSize:12,fontWeight:'500'}}>Share News</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```